# How to do a multiple insert using LAST_INSERT_ID() MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have 3 tables:

- customer
- email
- phone

Everyone of them with its own `AUTO_INCREMENT id (id_customer, id_email, id_phone)` and I have 2 more tables to relate them:

- customer_email
- customer_phone

These tables contain the others's tables ids as foreign keys.

How can I relate them in a single SQL statement using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`? Or what do you recommend?

Comment: What exactly you want ? Is there any query you have written where you stuck  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the results of LAST_INSERT_ID() using variables.

```sql
INSERT INTO email(...) VALUES (...);
SET @email_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO phone(...) VALUES (...);
SET @phone_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO customer_phone(id_email, id_phone) VALUES(@email_id, @phone_id);
```

Comment: What if I insert a customer needed two phone numbers inserted at once? How would you 'loop' through to associate each phone number with the customer?